# When I run a script which is attached to my canvas to pop up a pause menu it only runs once

Tags: c#, user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine

I attached a script to my canvas called PauseMenu which runs once and pauses initially and resumes but never pauses again when clicking escape. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using RTS;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

Canvas canvas;
private Player player;
public Button Button2;


void Start()
{
    Debug.Log ("asdf");
    player = transform.root.GetComponent< Player >();
    canvas = GetComponent<Canvas>();
    canvas.enabled = false;
    ResourceManager.MenuOpen = false;
    Button2.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Resume();});
}

void Update()
{
    Debug.Log ("Jake");
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && ResourceManager.MenuOpen == false) Pause();
    //Button2.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Resume();});
    //if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) Pause();
    //if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && ResourceManager.MenuOpen == true) Resume();
}

public void Pause()
{
    //if(Event.current.type == KeyCode.Escape)Debug.Log ("as12d12f2");
    //if(Event.current.type == EventType.KeyDown)Debug.Log ("as12d12f2");
    Debug.Log ("asdf2");
    canvas.enabled = true;
    Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
    if(player) player.GetComponent< UserInput >().enabled = false;
    //canvas.enabled = !canvas.enabled;
    //Time.timeScale = Time.timeScale == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    //ResourceManager.MenuOpen = true;
}

public void ResumePublic(){
    Resume ();
    }

private void Resume() {
    Debug.Log ("asdf1");
    Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    GetComponent< PauseMenu >().enabled = false;
    if(player) player.GetComponent< UserInput >().enabled = true;
    Cursor.visible = false;
    canvas.enabled = false;
    //Screen.showCursor = false;
    //GetComponent<UserInput > ().enabled = true;
    Debug.Log ("a2323sdf1");
    ResourceManager.MenuOpen = false;
    Button2.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Resume();});
}

public void Quit()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR 
    EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
    #else 
    Application.Quit();
    #endif
}
}
```

What is happening is that this is attached to the parent object canvas which has the child object panel which has child objects button1,2and3 . And when the user presses escape the menu should pop up, pause time(which it does) and resume when either the resume button is clicked (button2) or escape is pressed however this only works once and the code no longer runs (ie the update procedure is no longer running) - please can someone help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Resume() you set the PauseMenu Component to false

```
GetComponent< PauseMenu >().enabled = false;
```

But you did nothing to turn back that component in your pause function. So the script get disable after the first toggle and is never running again.

Could this be the problem?

Comment: Thanks :) Stupid of me not to see it